# How to marshal ignoring the struct options?

Tags: json, go

I have a struct similar to this:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    Type                   int     `json:"operatortypeid,string"`
    Cost                   float32 `json:"cost,string"`
    CostPerTransaction     float32 `json:"cost_per_transaction,string"`
}
```

I'm using the *string* option because the data I receive in the json request is always quoted, but I want to add some type safety in order to process and send it to the data base.

On Unmarshalling, the data types are correct, but when I marshall back into json it applies the struct option *string*, which makes it all quoted.

Is there any way to marshall the struct and have it ignore the struct options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly, but because struct tags are only metadata, they don't affect conversion; so you can do something like:

```
type MyStructIn struct {
    Type                   int     `json:"operatortypeid,string"`
    Cost                   float32 `json:"cost,string"`
    CostPerTransaction     float32 `json:"cost_per_transaction,string"`
}

type MyStructOut struct {
    Type                   int     
    Cost                   float32 
    CostPerTransaction     float32 
}

in := MyStructIn{}
json.Unmarshal(input, &in)
out := MyStructOut(in)
output,_ := json.Marshal(&out)
```