# How to unmarshall dynamic XML in fixed struct?

Tags: xml, go, struct, unmarshalling

I've a problem with unmarshalling different XML in fixed structs.
This is some examples of XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss>
<channel>
 <title>Città di Firenze - Sito istituzionale del comune di Firenze</title>
 <link>https://www.comune.fi.it/</link>
 <description/>
 <language>it</language>
  <item>
   <title>Convocazione Consiglio di Quartiere 3</title>
    <link>https://www.comune.fi.it/dalle-redazioni/convocazione-consiglio-di-quartiere-3-8</link>
    <description> &lt;br /&gt; Venerdì 29 Gennaio alle ore 18,00 è convocato il Consiglio di Quartiere in seduta telematica e potrà essere seguita in streaming;</description>
    <pubDate>Thu, 28 Jan 2021 12:13:50 +0100</pubDate>
    <dc:creator>Redazione</dc:creator>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">1761cfa1-afc4-4ded-b394-fe789229082a</guid>
  </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

```
<response>
 <item key="0">
   <field_bulletin_extra_date>24 Ott 2020</field_bulletin_extra_date>
   <field_bulletin_extra_date_1>Sat, 24 Oct 2020 12:00:00+0000</field_bulletin_extra_date_1>
   <title>24 Ott 2020</title>
   <field_abstract>Grazie </field_abstract>
   <uid>Redazione</uid>
   <view_node>Link</view_node>
   <field_parole_chiave>mobilità, IF, sicurezza stradale</field_parole_chiave>
   <field_contenuto_articolo>Dopo </field_contenuto_articolo>
</item>
</response>
```

I created distinct structs:

```golang
type RedazioneComuneFiData struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"rss"`
    Title    *string  `xml:"channel>title"`
    Link     *string  `xml:"channel>link"`
    Language *string  `xml:"channel>language"`
    ItemList []*Item  `xml:"channel>item"`
}

type Item struct {
    Title       *string `xml:"title"`
    Link        *string `xml:"link"`
    Description *string `xml:"description"`
    PubDate     *string `xml:"pubDate"`
    Creator     *string `xml:"dc:creator"`
}
```

```golang
type ComunicatiStampaComuneFiData struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name                        `xml:"response"`
    ItemList []*ComunicatiStampaComuneFiItem `xml:"item"`
}

type ComunicatiStampaComuneFiItem struct {
    Title         *string `xml:"title"`
    ID            *string `xml:"uid"`
    FieldAbstract *string `xml:"field_abstract"` // description or abstract
    ViewNode      *string `xml:"view_node"`      // link
    ReadableDate  *string `xml:"field_bulletin_extra_date"`
    Date          *string `xml:"field_bulletin_extra_date_1"`
    Content       *string `xml:"field_contenuto_articolo"`
    Keywords      *string `xml:"field_parole_chiave"`
}
```

and for unmarshaling I simply did:

```golang
var comunicatiStampaComuneFiData ComunicatiStampaComuneFiData
err = xml.Unmarshal(contents, &comunicatiStampaComuneFiData)
```

```golang
var redazioneComuneFiResponse RedazioneComuneFiData
err = xml.Unmarshal(contents, &redazioneComuneFiResponse)
```

I need to distinct structs because I have to use their fields in other parts, but I'd like to generalise the unmarshaling process for some future XMLs as well. I tried to implement `xml.Unmarshaller` interface, but without success.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question/situation, but I think you can do the same approach as used for JSON here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65816430/how-to-marshal-ignoring-the-struct-options/65816469#65816469

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not the solution. I have certainly explained the problem wrong. I wouldn't want to write the unmarshaling process every time I implement a new structure. I would like to have a "generic" code for unmarshaling and instantiate the object only under certain conditions, for example distinguishing tag values. I have seen that many people implement the `UnmarshalXML` method of the` Unmarshaler` interface to do similar things

Comment: I don't think there is any way you'll be able to do this without some implementation specific to each structure.